# What coding language do I need to learn to make a widget builder?

Tags: ruby, twitter, web-applications, widget, twitter-anywhere

stackoverflow community. I'm new here and I just started learning how to code in ruby with the goal of making a twitter widget maker. Do I need to learn any other languages to make it work?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Ghilia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know any html, css, or javascript? These are essential in creating just about any custom web content.

Also, have you considered following along on some youtube tutorials?

Here are some that really helped me out in using different rails gems when I was starting out:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-1HCWbu7iU&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPLNdRYB_QyomQsShx59tpc-

And finally, Michael Hartl's tutorial :

https://www.railstutorial.org/book

**Hartl actually builds a twitter app**. Incredible tutorial but it can take months. He uses very little external libraries. This is considered one of the best web application tutorials ever made.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot. I don't know any javascript and I'm a little rusty with my html and css. I'll try to get back in to it.

Comment: Awesome. Persistence is key, keep at it